# Handsontable in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, handsontable, ipywidgets

I was wondering if anyone currently uses handsontable in a Jupyter notebook. I have been following instructions from:

https://gist.github.com/rossant/9463955

https://gist.github.com/rdhyee/9897356

However, these instructions do not work with the current versions of the notebook/ipywidgets and are very outdated.

I would like to implement the following handsontable example:http://jsfiddle.net/handsoncode/s6t768pq/

When I load handsontable.full.css and handsontable.full.js into the notebook, I do not get any errors. However, I get this error: ***ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined*** when trying to run the following code in the notebook (this may not be the correct code to do this though).

```
%%javascript
requirejs.config({
    paths: { 
        'handsontable': ['http://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.0/bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full'],
    },
});

require(['handsontable'], function(handsontable) {
    console.log("Loaded :)");   

  var data = function () {
    return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100, 10);
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('example');

  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data(),
    minSpareCols: 1,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });

  return{};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The two gists that you referenced are very outdated and will require quite a bit rehab to work with ipywidgets 7.0, and jupyter notebook 5.0 in a python >= 3.5 env. Without knowing specifically which errors you have encountered it will be very difficult to diagnose your problem.

However you could try to use [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) which works with ipywidgets 6.0.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the question to show a simple example of inserting a handsontable into the notebook. I had looked into qgrid before, but I was afraid to use it since it is not being actively developed. I will look into it again though.